# Regex Find Raw E-mail Addresses that Hasn't Been Linked in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, regex, html-email

I'm trying to create a regex that finds raw e-mail addresses from a long body text that hasn't been linked yet in HTML. For instance,

- `<a href="mailto:name@example.com">name@example.com</a>` should return false
- `name@example.com` should return true

and I would like to replace them with properly linked e-mail addresses.

I've tried:

```js
html = html.replaceAll(
/(?:(?!href=['"]mailto:)(?!<a.*?>))([a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?:(?!<\/a>))/gi, 
"<a href=\'mailto:$1\'>$1</a>"
);
```

The idea is that to find e-mail addresses that do not have `href='mailto:` or the `<a>` tag before the e-mail, and do not have `</a>` after the e-mail. However, it appears that the negative lookahead `?!` is not giving me the intended result:

```js
let regex = new RegExp(/(?:(?!href=['"]mailto:)(?!<a.*?>))([a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?:(?!<\/a>))/, 'gi');
console.log(regex.test("href='mailto:name@example.com"))
```

As you can see from the above snippet, despite adding the negative lookahead, testing `href='mailto:name@example.com` against the regex is returning true.

I also tried:

```
(.*)^(?:(?!href=['"]mailto:)(?!<a.*?>))([a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?:(?!<\/a>))
```

it doesn't match e-mails with the `href='mailto:` prefix but now

```
regex.test("1: name@example.com") // returns false
```

The e-mail addresses can be inline so I can't use the `^` operator at the beginning.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to do a regex replacement with a callback function on the following pattern:

```regex
<a href="mailto:\S+">.*?<\/a>|\S+@\S+\.\S+
```

This uses an alternation trick to try to first find anchor tags which already have email addresses in them.  That failing, the alternation falls back to finding email addresses anywhere else in the text.

```js
var input = "Here is a tag with email <a href=\"mailto:name@example.com\">name@example.com</a> and here is just the email name@example.com";
console.log("INPUT: " + input);
var output = input.replace(/<a href="mailto:\S+">.*?<\/a>|\S+@\S+\.\S+/g, function(match, contents, offset, inp)
    {
        if (/<a href="mailto:\S+">.*?<\/a>/.test(match)) {
            return match;
        }
        else {
            return "<a href=\"mailto:" + match + "\">" + match + "<\/a>";
        }
    }
);
console.log("OUTPUT: " + output);
```

In the code snippet above, the callback function checks if the match be an anchor tag already having an email address, in which case it just returns the same match.  For all other email addresses, it wraps them in an anchor tag and then returns that replacement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Perfectly solved my problem. I want to add that using `\S` to find e-mail address characters might be a little risky - when an e-mail address is wrapped around parenthesis, which sometimes happens in the text I'm going through, the parenthesis will be added to the e-mail address. Limiting to alphanumeric characters (and some special that are allowed) using `[a-zA-Z0-9+._-]` or `\w` might be a better option

Comment: @Parzival Agree with your comment on the regex I used for emails...if you poke around SO, you can easily find much better (and way more complex) regex patterns for email.  I'll leave that up to your own preference.  I only tried to give you a general framework here.